# GCP - Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80131500

Tags: google-app-engine, .net-core

I'm trying to go through the App Engine Quickstart tutorial for .Net and running into a problem with the dotnet cli.

I'm able to clone the git repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples.git $TUTORIALDIR
```

But when I do the restore, I get the following error:

```
dotnet restore
Failed to initialize CoreCLR, HRESULT: 0x80131500
```

There are plenty of references to the error online - typically dealing with missing packages, but I'm assuming that shouldn't be an issue on GCP?

I'm pretty new to the dotnet cli and GCP, so I'm looking for some pointers on how to proceed/troubleshoot.